# Error extraño con display:inline-block

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy creando una web y necesito colocar dos div uno al lado de otro. He usado display:inline-block y vertical-align:top, pero me ocurre algo muy raro: El texto del div de la derecha sólo se muestra donde debe si el `<p>` es de una línea; en el momento en que pongo un texto largo se pasa directamente a debajo del div de la izquierda.

```css
.caja-trabajo {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.caja-titulo {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.caja-titulo p {
    margin:0px;
}

.caja-izquierda {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.foto-empresa {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.descripcion-empresa {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.descripcion-empresa p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.caja-derecha {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
}

.caja-derecha p:first-child {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja-trabajo">
  
<div class="caja-titulo">
<p>Mayo 2013 - Mayo 2015</p>
</div>
  
<div class="caja-izquierda">
<div class="foto-empresa"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png"></div>
<div class="descripcion-empresa"><p style="font-weight: bold">Hola</p></div>  
</div>

<div class="caja-derecha">
<p>Descripción</p>
<p>Roger Torrent recogió este sábado la estela de Carme Forcadell y orquestó un frente -en el que logró integrar a los comunes- para plantar cara a la Justicia y proseguir con el desafío al Estado que inauguró su antecesora en el cargo cuando aprobó las «leyes de desconexión» y permitió aprobar la declaración unilateral de independencia en el Parlament.Tomando el testigo de la diputada republicana hoy procesada y encarcelada, Torrent mantuvo convocado el Pleno de investidura, pero no permitió votar al aún candidato a la Presidencia de la Generalitat, Jordi Turull -como le había pedido antes de ingresar en prisión- para evitar desobedecer explícitamente al Tribunal Constitucional y aumentar la nómina de independentistas investigados.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Necesitas que la estructura del html se quede como está o puede cambiar?

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) o un sistema de grietas como el que tiene [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), eso te facilitará muchas cosas, ahorrarás mucho código y el frontend cargará más rápido si usas CDN. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, he investigado un poco más eso de flexbox y era la solución que buscaba.

Comment: @silenciovirus ¿Podrías compartir la solución con la que has conseguido tu objetivo? De esta manera, otra gente que llegue a tu pregunta podrá ver como lo has solucionado y puede que les sea útil :)

Comment: De nada, es un placer ayudarte.

Comment: Hecho @FranciscoRomero, he explicado la solución al final del post original.

Comment: @silenciovirus publicalo como respuesta y luego la puedes aceptar. De esta manera queda mucho más claro que hay una respuesta y que ha sido válida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO. Gracias a todos por responder. La solución fue crear un div que abarcase caja-izquerda y caja-derecha y darle un display:flex

Answer (score 1):

Le agregue a ambas **div.caja-derecha** y **div.caja-izquierda** un **width:50%** y luego le agregue a div.caja-derecha **float:left** y parece hacer lo que tratas de hacer que es tener ambas divs una al lado de la otra. Para mas seguridad tambien deverias poner ambas en un contenedor (div) y darle a éste un clearfix.

Comment: Gracias, finalmente lo solucioné con un flexbox, como me indicó otro compañero. Tú solución no era mala, pero el flexbox me parece más optimo.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a plantear una solución que no es la ideal (yo usaría flexbox o una grilla), asumiendo que no podemos modificar el HTML.

Consiste en utilizar `calc()` para determinar el ancho del contenedor de la derecha, asumiendo que el ancho del contenedor de la izquierda es conocido y "fijo".

Tomamos el 100% del ancho del contenedor padre, le restamos 200px de la imagen, 2 pixeles más por el borde a cada lado, otros 20px por el padding a cada lado de la imagen, los 10px de padding de la caja de la derecha, y por último los 4 pixeles típicos que hay entre dos elementos inline-block cuando están separados por un "enter" o un espacio en HTML.

En total serían 200 + 2 + 20 + 10 + 4 = 236

```css
.caja-trabajo {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.caja-titulo {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.caja-titulo p {
    margin:0px;
}

.caja-izquierda {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.foto-empresa {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.descripcion-empresa {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.descripcion-empresa p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.caja-derecha {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 236px);
}

.caja-derecha p:first-child {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja-trabajo">
  
<div class="caja-titulo">
<p>Mayo 2013 - Mayo 2015</p>
</div>
  
<div class="caja-izquierda">
<div class="foto-empresa"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Square_200x200.png"></div>
<div class="descripcion-empresa"><p style="font-weight: bold">Hola</p></div>  
</div>

<div class="caja-derecha">
<p>Descripción</p>
<p>Roger Torrent recogió este sábado la estela de Carme Forcadell y orquestó un frente -en el que logró integrar a los comunes- para plantar cara a la Justicia y proseguir con el desafío al Estado que inauguró su antecesora en el cargo cuando aprobó las «leyes de desconexión» y permitió aprobar la declaración unilateral de independencia en el Parlament.Tomando el testigo de la diputada republicana hoy procesada y encarcelada, Torrent mantuvo convocado el Pleno de investidura, pero no permitió votar al aún candidato a la Presidencia de la Generalitat, Jordi Turull -como le había pedido antes de ingresar en prisión- para evitar desobedecer explícitamente al Tribunal Constitucional y aumentar la nómina de independentistas investigados.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

Creería que se puede encontrar una solución también con `white-space: nowrap;` y `white-space: normal;` pero tal vez otra persona nos pueda ayudar con ese.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sí podía modificar el html, por eso lo arreglé añadiendo un div con display:flex, como me indicó un compañero. Pero me guardo tu respuesta porque me puede valer para otros casos donde no puedo modificar html.